# Windows vs Linux PHP PHP_EOL - php data different

Tags: php, rhel8, jbase

I migrated a script from windows to rhel 8 and I have the following code in my php script:

```
$Data = file_get_contents('https://example.com/api/data'); 
$Array = json_decode($Data, true);
$Output = '';
foreach ($Array as $key => $value) {
 if ($Output != ''){$Output .= PHP_EOL;}
 $Output .= $value["id"] . ":" . $value["status"];
}
file_put_contents($Response,$Output);
```

In windows, it puts a nice new line in the data.  In hrel it is not.

I did a simple test:

```
$Output = '1';
$Output .= PHP_EOL;
$Output .= '2';
$Output .= PHP_EOL;
$Output .= '3';
file_put_contents($Response,$Output);
```

If I do a hexdump I get the following:

```
sh-4.4$ hexdump -c active.resp
0000000   1  \n   2  \n   3
0000005
```

and

```
sh-4.4$ hexdump active.resp
0000000 0a31 0a32 0033
0000005
```

The hexdump with the -c looks correct.

If I create the same file with vi, the hexdump shows an additional \n and in hex,
0a31 0a32 0a33

I added an extra PHP_EOL at the end of the $output and it worked and the hexdump shows exactly the same as the hexdump on the vi created file.

I am at a loss.  Do I need to add a newline before doing file_put_contents on linux?

Can someone please explain this and the hexdump without the last php_eol?

Comment: Try to var_dump the `$Output` before file_put_contents to see if the line break is correct before saving to the file.

Comment: What program/method are you using to inspect the output file?

Comment: I just opened the data with notepad++ and it is correct.  I am reading this file with a jbase basic program and that must be doing something to the data.  Should I delete this question?  It is not a php issue.

Comment: Perhaps instead you could update the question instead with your findings, and change the tags

Comment: Yeah, good idea.  When I find the solution, I will update.

Comment: `\012` looks like a correct octal dump of good old Unix new line character. If it's nothing but a display issue, the question is very unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: Mind sharing which version of jBASE you're running on?

Comment: Jbase 5.7 just did a complete update on the question because there is some issue with the file getting created without a newline character at the end and jbase not liking that.

Comment: Mind running a `jdiag` to pinpoint the exact release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this.  Here is what I am pretty sure happened.  In linux, lines end with a new line.  I built this data by concatenation without a newline (or more accurately an EOL) at the end.  This must not be an issue with windows.  I added a newline at the end and it now handles it fine.  When jbase reads a file like this, it reads it as raw data I think, right or wrong.